# Symfony 2 Allowed memory size vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Unescaper.php

Tags: php, symfony

I move my symfony2 app on the new serwer.
But in my new serwer display only one error (on app.php and app_dev.php) :

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 3002456313 bytes) in .../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Yaml/Unescaper.php on line 56

I dont find any problem like this in google. 
I try to solve this problem for two days.

Comment: I'd guess that PHP is trying to allocate more memory then is allowed by the PHP config. Try and see if you can make more RAM available.

Comment: But 3002456313 bytes = 2.79 gigabytes. This is simple app in my first server this app usage only 22mb memory. 

Sory for my english, i know, not is good. I cant make more RAM unfortunately

Comment: Exactly, and allowed is `134217728B` which is `128M`. However, if you say this is some simple app that should be quite enough. Maybe it's a bug within `Yaml` - did you try `composer update`?

Comment: I update, but without effect

Comment: Btw, which version of `Symfony2` do you have installed?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be something about Doctrine (in fact, pretty sure). Are you managing a big set of entities? This means that you are loading a huge collection of entities (maybe a xtomany relation) and you are loading full collection into the memory.

Could you revise if is something about this?

Comment: Hmm. I traing delete my bundle (leaving main file bundle, AppKernel must found this file. If will not find this file, display error " Class 'Ptp\MainBundle\PtpMainBundle' not found in 19" , the obvious) error "Allowed memory size ...." continue to display ;/

Comment: not talking about bundle, talking about any kind of Doctrine query or traversing. Pretty sure is that. It could also be an infinite loop caused by some strange code.